# Unescape special characters in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL block which takes description and insert into one table, e.g.:

```
description := 'test\ndescription';
```

I will get the above value from external source.

but If I insert description value directly `\n` will be considered as two characters. I want to consider \n as special character and insert into db.

Kindly let me know if I missed something or not clear.

Comment: pl/sql has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to store `\n` as new line in database?
How about something like that:

```
SELECT replace('te\nst', '\n', CHR(10)) FROM DUAL
```

Comment: This is fine. Can you suggest something that will take care of all special characters like \t \r

Comment: I do not know about existing function that would do that. I think you need to write your own that will handle each special character in the way I have provided in my answer. But of course there could be module for Oracle that already does that and I just didn't find it.